# Expo: not loading assets on AppLoading

Tags: expo

**Update:** I build the app shortly after asking the question and found out that there is no slow loading in the app in production.
I will let the question stay, so some hopefully can benefit from my findings - that there is a big difference in performance between an Expo an a standalone app....

When my Expo app starts, the icons load slowly  on Android (I have not tried on iOS). I try to use `AppLoading` to cache the icons, but nothing happens. The icons still show later than the rest of the components on the home screen (1-4 seconds).
Have I misunderstood how `AppLoading` and `Font.loadAsync` work? Aren't they supposed to load on the first run and then subsequent reloads will render the icons immediately?

I have asked [google](https://github.com/brentvatne/expo-issue-368/blob/master/App.js) and followed Expo' [Preloading & Caching Assets](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/) and the [full working example](https://github.com/expo/new-project-template/blob/master/App.js), but nothing seem to happen.

Following Expo's "Preloading and caching Assets":

```
async _loadAssetsAsync() {
    const imageAssets = cacheImages([
        require("./assets/logo.png"),
        require("./assets/logoText.png"),
    ]);

    const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
        Ionicons.font,
        FontAwesome.font,
        MaterialCommunityIcons.font,
    ]);

    await Promise.all([...imageAssets, ...fontAssets]);
}
```

I have also tried requires: `require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf")`and `...Icon.Ionicons.font` in the same example.

Am I missing something completely obvious like only works in production or can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you mean when you say the "icons load slowly"? Is it in the order of 100ms delay, or 2 seconds, or more? Is this on iOS or Android? Can you provide repository that I can clone and try this in to verify for myself? I cannot reproduce any 'slow loading' by initializing a new project with `expo init` and choosing the tabs template, all of the icons load instantly.

Comment: It seems to work in the built apk so I have updated the question. I still have the issue when using the Expo SDK though.

The slow loading is up to four seconds and I have only tried in on Android. I have tried to make a reproducible project, but the icons load a lot faster there so my guess is that I have an old phone and/or my code is not performant enough.

Right now I am using three font types. Is it better to stick with one performance-wise or doesn't it make a noticable difference?